# PHP: Function to change text to PNG image with transparency

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to change a section of text into an image. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code and also how to make it transparent. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?PHP 
function fsrep_imageaddress($address, $listingid) {
    $font_size = 4; 
    $width  = imagefontwidth($font_size)*strlen($address); 
    $height = imagefontheight($font_size); 
    $img = imagecreate($width,$height); 
    $bg    = imagecolorallocate($img, 25, 25, 25); 
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); 
    $len = strlen($address); 
    $ypos = 0; 
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){ 
        $xpos = $i * imagefontwidth($font_size); 
        imagechar($img, $font_size, $xpos, $ypos, $address, $color); 
        $address = substr($address, 1);    

    } 
    imagepng($img, ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/address-'.$listingid.'.png',100);
    imagedestroy($img);
}   

fsrep_imageaddress(Just Testing, 12)
?>
```

Comment: What is your script currently doing wrong? First thing you need to do is put `Just Testing` in quotes, as it's a string not a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is it not working?**

If you look in the error log, you'll see you need to put "Just Testing" in quotes (thanks @scrowler!) in the function call. Then you'll get an error that `imagepng` takes a quality level of 0 (no compression) to 9 (max). You have 100! Here, I set it to 5 (medium compression).

```
imagepng($img, ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/address-'.$listingid.'.png',5);
```

**How do I set a transparent background?**

There's a weird thing with palette images (ie those created with `imagecreate`). The first colour allocated is set as the background, and can't be transparent - so you need to create a dummy color and then convert it to transparent.

```
// after this line
$bg = imagecolorallocate($img, 25, 25, 25); 
// add this
imagecolortransparent($img, $bg);
```

**Result**

I made these changes and changed the text to red (255,0,0) for readability and got this:

[image: Result of code changes]